# Installed un-encrypted Ubuntu 16.04 on encrypted Windows Machine - Unsecure?

Tags: software-installation, security, encryption

I installed Windows 10 Pro with bitlocker encryption for an employee. He is a developer, so common practice is they install Linux. He installed Ubuntu 16.04 but did not select encryption when he did the install. Does that mean that his machine is now unsecure?

Answer (score 1):

You always need the right key to decrypt the Windows data. So, although you have an unencrypted Ubuntu partition, it doesn't mean that the Windows data is now unencrypted as well. The two OS are totally separated from each other.

Comment: However, if someone booted the machine from a live USB, then the Ubuntu data would be up for grabs.

Comment: Thanks for the thought guys. Although, I will clarify, there's nothing in the Windows partition. My main concern is what's on Ubuntu because he's accessing all of our systems through that. So I wanted to know if the Ubuntu partition is unsecure.

Comment: OK, then you may further specify what exactly do you mean by Ubuntu partition is unsecure? Do you mean that your whole network is vulnerable to spy attacks?